# No such file or directory iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am trying to get size of the file by its path. Those files are saved videos from my app. i used the below code its returning the error saying there is no file or directory.

```
NSString *urlPath = [self.localPathArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSError *err;
NSDictionary * properties = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:urlPath error:&err];
```

This is how am saving the file path after downloading the file

```
 - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session assetDownloadTask:
(AVAssetDownloadTask *)assetDownloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {


        NSString *localPath = location.relativePath;
        NSLog(@"localPath: %@", localPath);

       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:self.localPathArray forKey:@"AssetPath"];
    }
```

See the error screenshot and my app storage details screenshot below
[image: Error]
[image: Storage details]

Comment: can you print your urlPath

Comment: yes , i can print the file path, i can play video using the filepath in avplayer

Comment: @Codecracker How these paths are stored ?

Comment: from didFinishDownloadingToURL method , i am saving it in NSUserdefaults

Comment: @Codecracker Can you add that code with the question ?

Comment: added, please check

Comment: can you print this `NSLog(@"localPath: %@", localPath);`

Comment: are you missed onething you forget to append your `NSString *localPath` to `self.localPathArray`

Comment: yes i can print that

Comment: add `[self.localPathArray addObject: localPath ];` then store your into NSUserDefaults

Comment: i did that but i removed while adding that snippet in so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190338/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-code-cracker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The **path** with reference to **root directory** is called **absolute**. The **path** with reference to **current directory** is called **relative**

so try

```
 NSString *localPath = location.path;
```

instead of

```
  NSString *localPath = location.relativePath;
```

for e.g

```
  - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session assetDownloadTask:
(AVAssetDownloadTask *)assetDownloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {


        NSString *localPath = location.path;
        NSLog(@"localPath: %@", localPath);
        [self.localPathArray addObject: localPath];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:self.localPathArray forKey:@"AssetPath"];
    }
```

for sample see this answer already answered in [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278407/nsurlsessiondownloadtask-downloads-but-ends-with-error)